# Javascript write/render image on asp.net page

Tags: javascript

I am calling a javascript function (function test()) which calls a url which returns a html script. I want to render that on to the page.

I am using this, but when I go to view source I am not seeing any image..

```
function test()
{
    document.write('<SCR'+'IPT SRC="http://demoweb.com/renderimage;type=a;num='+ 1000 +'?" type="text/javascript"></SCR'+'IPT>');
}
```

This retuns URL http://demoweb.com/renderimage;type=a;num=1000? (if I paste it in browser)

```
document.write("<img src='http://demoweb/?ct=0:abg22&adv=43nn3gg&fmt=2' width='1' height='1' border='0'/>");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A browser's View Source shows the HTML as-downloaded from the server, not the page's DOM after any scripts have run. For that you'd use a DOM browser, such as Firefox's DOM Inspector or Firebug, or IE's Developer Tools.

Use of `document.write` is not recommended because it causes a re-parse of the document. It's better to use DOM manipulation methods instead.

Try this:

```
var img = document.createElement("img");
img.src = "http://demoweb/?ct=0:abg22&adv=43nn3gg&fmt=2";

var imgParent = document.getElementById("whatever");
imgParent.appendChild( img );
```

Comment: instead of adding it to the "whatever" image. How do I write that to body? is it just document.getElementById("body") ?

Comment: `var htmlBody = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];`